# Linux filesystem cache and deleting lots of files

Tags: linux, cache, sd-card

I sometimes have a need to delete large directory tree with lots small files from an SD card. Fastest way seems to copy the whole SD card to local disk with DD, mount it via loopback, do operations and write it back.

I have understood that the Linux filesystem cache is FS block-level, so I wonder if it's possible to configure it to do something similar automatically?

Comment: what filesystem is on the SD card?

Comment: @erik258 It's FAT32

Comment: Mount SD card without `sync` option.

Comment: FAT32 is not quite suitable for large folders and large operations. Is it because your device doesn't support other FS?

Comment: Search for `rsync` to delete files. It should faster. If you need your steps, you can create a virtual disk and work on that (but always with `rsync`).